# Having trouble getting a string of symbols to break inside a table cell in PDF outputs generated in Oxygen

Tags: css, xml, pdf-generation, oxygenxml

Some tables in our PDFs have a string like the following: >>>>>>>>>>>9. In our PDF outputs, we use the overflow-wrap attribute to force long words to break within cells and not bleed. However, this doesn't force the >>>>>>>>>>9 string to break.

We're using Oxygen XML Editor 20.1 to generate PDFs using DITA and CSS. Our tables consists of the following element hierarchy:

table
  tgroup
    row
     thead
     tbody
       entry
         p

We use the overflow-wrap: break-word; attribute at the entry level to break long words. This doesn't work on the string of symbols described above.

We have tried setting the attribute to anywhere, with no result. Tried using word-wrap and word-break as alternatives, but nothing.

```
    *[class~="topic/table"] {
        table-layout:fixed;
        width: 100%;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
     } 

    *[class~="topic/table"] *[class~="topic/entry"] {
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
```

Expected result:

string of symbols breaks without a hyphen (soft hyphen) and continues in the cell without bleeding

Actual result:

String of symbols bleeds into next cells without breaking

Answer (score 0):

Using Oxygen's "Insert From Character map" (from the main "Edit" menu) you can search for a character called "zero width space" and add it manually inside the content. It will not show up but the PDF processor will be able to break the line there when producing the PDF.

Comment: Hi Radu, thanks for the response. Unfortunately, we can't do this manually as our documentation is too frequent and the instances where similar strings occur are too many. An Oxygen team member did reply to this question on the Oxygen Forums saying that they would investigate adding the option to wrap strings of symbols in a later build. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: One solution might be to create an XSLT customization template for the publishing stage which matches the text in cells and inserts zero width space characters between various characters there. https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/20.1/ug-editor/topics/pdf-xslt-extensions.html